# MySQL procedure not returning first row

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

Does the `execute()` statement perform an implicit `fetch()`? PHP does not show the first row of the returned result in the following simple code:

```
$query = 'CALL `MySP`()';

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();        
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $rows;
```

`$rows` contains only 3 rows instead of actual 4; the first one is missing. The same SP returns 4 rows when run directly.

### Edit

No luck yet after I tried everything suggested in the comments. Additionally I found that PDO can fail for very simple SPs too. Here is an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Test`()
BEGIN
  SELECT 123 as Col1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 456 as Col1;
END
```

Try calling this proc from PHP. PDO throws a "no clue" exception when you try to fetch:

> PDO error: “ SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error ” ...

Comment: What's the contents of the SP?

Comment: A `SELECT` statement with a few `JOIN`s, some `GROUP`ing and `ORDER`ing; those usual SQL suspects.

Comment: You could try removing th backticks from the proceedure name. and there is no point preparing a call to a SP, try using a simple `->query($query);`

Comment: And NO `execute()` does not perform a fetch

Comment: Removed ticks and called `query()`. Still 3 rows.

Comment: `$stmt->rowCount()` also returns 3.

Comment: And what if you run the full query in the code instead of the SP?

Comment: Running full query outside of the SP returns 4 rows as well, which means it is not MySQL's fault.

Comment: Does the sql in the stored procedure consist of more than one result-producing query? or have iteration that would execute such a query more than once?

Comment: No. Only one. There are subqueries within it, but there is only one outer SELECT statement. MySQL Workbench also shows one result set with 4 rows.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call)

Comment: No luck. Calling `nextRecordset()` immediately after `fetchAll()` returns `false`.

Comment: ....and here is the obligatory "are you sure both are accessing the same database/server?" question.

Comment: I have to think this is specific to your environment - if this was a general PDO or MySQL bug it would have been caught and fixed a long time ago.

Comment: Yeah. I'm still trying to eliminate other factors, but thus far can't see any good reason for this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried setting delimiters in your procedure definition?

Comment: I just copied the entire `SELECT` statement from my SP and pasted it in PHP to be run as a query. It is still returning 3 rows, whereas pasting the same query in Workbench returns 4 rows. :( I'm soooo dead...

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear, but that's what I had asked with "And what if you run the full query in the code instead of the SP?"

Comment: I just manipulated data a bit more, so now the SP is returning 2 rows instead of 4, and PDO is now returning 1 row instead of 2. It is not bringing in the first row, just as it was doing before. This also confirmed that I was not connecting to two different servers/DBs by chance.

Comment: What is the PHP code that you're using to view the results of the query?  What you're showing appears to be the contents of a function.  How is that function called and what do you to with the returned value?

Comment: I'm debugging it in Eclipse and using Eclipse debugging tools (variable tips, Expression window etc.) to check results. These results are then fed into a ChartJS object. That Chart also shows one row missing.

Comment: Disclaimer is that I'm not a PHP/Eclipse guy, so just trying to find my path here.

Comment: @PatrickQ: See my answer. And thanks for being with me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!

This is so very stupid. Not sure who to blame. It ruined my entire night and turned out to be just the fact that I was using `Count` as alias for one of my columns. PDO somehow doesn't like this and as a result removes the first row of the result set. I'm pretty sure there would be a logical explanation of this unexpected behavior, since MySQL doesn't mind this alias.

Anyway changing `Count` to `RowCount` or anything else fixed the behavior.

Hope this helps someone down the road.

Thank you everyone who worked with me on this one.

Comment: Glad you were able to track it down.